# Can't make div background transparent

Tags: html, css

I'm helping a friend with this site:

http://smashingdivas.info/

No matter what style I apply to the gray background of the content div, I can't make it transparent (in any browser), so that the background image of the page shows through.

I've tried all of the following:

```
background-color: transparent;
background: transparent;
background-color: none;
background: none;
```

and nothing seems to work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you mean `opacity` rather than `transparency`?

Comment: I'd help but you put one of those "no right click" scripts on the page. It doesn't stop me from viewing your source, so its only purpose must be to annoy me for having the audacity to try to help.

Comment: not my page. that's part of her theme. i just use the menu to view the source.

Comment: Wut? Scripts? Just get yourself some noscript plugin and youll notice much less ads and silly scripts!

Comment: transparent background is the default for div, so if you don't specify a background the div's background will be transparent. The tricky aspect is that you then see the background of its parent. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the div with class 'container' it's because you have a rule in your HTML that is overwriting your CSS:

.container,
.sliderGallery { background-color: #111111; }

Comment: it's the div with container-inner class.

Comment: .container_inner doesn't have a background applied to it at all so it is transparent. You can just see the background-color from .container through it

Comment: i see it now. thanks! i wish there was a way to edit this on all pages for the theme at one time.

Comment: That is beauty of external CSS. You should really put all of your CSS in to files and link to them on the pages you need them. Then you have one place to control all your site styles

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply transparency just on the background there are 2 options:

1) you can set the "alpha" channel on RGB ie.

```
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
```

but this won't work on IE

2) create a simple transparent png image and set it this way

```
background:url(transparentIMG.png) repeat;
```

Comment: `background:url(transparentIMG.png) repeat;`
this didnt work for IE6

Comment: IE6 for me doesn't exist. (and transparent png was not supported in the middle ages)

Comment: [For IE6](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/making-png-image-transparency-work-in-internet-explorer/) this workaround might help someone

Comment: Tell me who still uses that crappy browser

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying the `opacity` property ?
like for eg.

`opacity:0.5;`

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, at least. I guess you're overriding the background properties via CSS due to some later rule again.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove following rule:

.container, .sliderGallery {
    background-color: #111111;
}